# Define Callback for components of a compound view

Tags: android, callback

I have a compound view in my android app composed of a Button and an EditText.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:text="CLEAR"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"

        android:hint="@string/Hint"        
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and class:

```
package com.example.compview;

import com.paad.todolist.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CompoundView extends LinearLayout{

    EditText myEditText;
    Button myButton;

    public CompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CompoundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        li.inflate(R.layout.compund_view, this, true);

        myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myEditText.setText("");             
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is no error but the Button callback is not considered (when I run the app, the button should clear the text of EditText but nothing happen). If I define the callback in the main class, everything is ok. I don't underestand what's wrong. whould anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try `View.onclickListener` instead of `Button.onClickListener`

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myEditText.setText("");             
            }
        });
```

Comment: both of them are correct or at at least work when I define callback in main class. I also tried both of them in the class I defined for compound view. no difference. it does not work!

Comment: instead of using myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  try using myEditText = (EditText)getChildAt(position);

Comment: Or you can change the way of inflating you view 
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View view= li.inflate(R.layout.compund_view, this, true);
myEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);